# knn train and class have different lengths

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

NN model to predict new data, but the error says: 
"'train' and 'class' have different lengths"

can someone replicate and solve this error?

```
weather <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
temperature <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
golf <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(weather, temperature, golf)
df_new <- data.frame(weather = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), temp = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), sunnday= c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0))
pred_knn <- knn(train=df[, c(1,2)], test=df_new, cl=df$golf, k=1)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knn function in R requires the training data to only contain independent variables, as the dependent variable is called separately in the "cl" parameter. Changing the line below will fix this particular error.

```
pred_knn <- knn(train=df[,c(1,2)], test=df_new, cl=df$golf, k=1)
```

However, note that running the above line will throw another error. Since knn calculates the Euclidean distance between observations, it requires all independent variables to be numeric. These pages have helpful related information. I would recommend using a different classifier for this particular data set.

https://towardsdatascience.com/k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm-with-examples-in-r-simply-explained-knn-1f2c88da405c
https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/how-to-resolve-error-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-6-in-knn/7280/4

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I updated my question. So I guess my problem in my data is that, the variable vector of df does not match to that of df_new which produces some trouble. However a k-fold cross validation worked. Maybe by luck I guess. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hey @stefan485, the idea is that both the train and test dataframes should have had the same schema and variables to work. that wasn't the case before, as you were including the dependent variable in the train dataframe too. The knn function in R uses the "cl" parameter to track the dependent variable, so it does not need to be a part of the train dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with data from the ISLR Weekly dataframe:

> knn.pred = knn(train$Lag2,test$Lag2,train$Direction,k=1)
> Error in knn(train$Lag2, test$Lag2, train$Direction, k = 1) :
> dims of 'test' and 'train' differ

where

> train = subset(Weekly, Year >= 1990 & Year <= 2008)
> test = subset(Weekly, Year < 1990 | Year > 2008)

I finally solved it by putting the test and the train in as.matrix() like this:

> knn.pred = knn(as.matrix(train$Lag2),as.matrix(test$Lag2),train$Direction,k=1)